# Convergence $\int_1^{\infty} x^2 \cos(e^x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I am learning about ways to test if an integral converges or diverges and I am stuck with this one:$$\int_1^{+\infty}x^2\cos(e^x)dx=?$$
UPD: I forgot to say that I had to explore absolute and conditional convergence.

Comment: Can you integrate it in the first place though?

Comment: Actually I think that it is possible because that was given to me by my teacher in university.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I meant are YOU able to integrate it?

Comment: It is impossible to integrate for me. I just need to explore if that integral converges or diverges.

Comment: It would be impossible for many people, be sure (not to say impossible).

Comment: At what point this became an improper integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $u = e^x$. Then

$$ \int_{1}^{R} x^2 \cos(e^x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{e}^{e^R} \frac{\log^2 u}{u} \cos u \, \mathrm{d}u. $$

Since $u \mapsto \frac{\log^2 u}{u}$ is decreasing for $u \geq e^2$ and vanishes as $u\to\infty$, the integral converges as $R\to\infty$ by the alternating series test. On the other hand, using the fact that $e^2 \leq 2.75\pi$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty} \left| x^2 \cos(e^x) \right| \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{e}^{\infty} \left| \frac{\log^2 u}{u} \cos u \right| \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&\geq \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \int_{n\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{n\pi} \left| \frac{\log^2 u}{u} \cos u \right| \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&\geq \frac{\pi}{4}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{\log^2 (n\pi)}{\pi n} \\
&= \infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: The substitution makes it much clearer...I had thought about it but decided (foolishly) against it.

Comment: @Integrand, Being a routine idea, I am quite certain that you would have easily come up with this idea. I guess the exponential factor $e^{-x}$ lured you away.

Answer (score 3):

The integral converges, but only conditionally. Introduce a factor to make IBP work out:
$$
I=\int _1^{\infty} x^2\cos(e^x)\,dx = \int _1^{\infty}\underbrace{x^2 e^{-x}}_u\cdot \underbrace{\cos(e^x)e^x\,dx }_{dv}
$$
$$
=\left.x^2 e^{-x} \sin(e^x)\right|_1^{\infty} +\int _1^{\infty}e^{-x}\sin(e^x)(x^2-2x)\,dx
$$
$$
=-\frac{\sin(e)}{e}+\int _1^{\infty}e^{-x}\sin(e^x)(x^2-2x)\,dx
$$For the last integral, by some very crude bounds we have
$$
\left|\int _1^{\infty}e^{-x}\sin(e^x)(x^2-2x)\,dx\right|\leq \int _1^{\infty}\left|e^{-x}\sin(e^x)(x^2-2x)\right|\,dx
$$
$$
\leq \int _1^{\infty}\left|e^{-x}(x^2-2x)\right|\,dx \leq \int _0^{\infty}\left|e^{-x}(x^2-2x)\right|\,dx
$$
$$
\leq \int _0^{\infty}e^{-x}(x^2+2x)\,dx =4;
$$Mathematica gives $0.0584793$ as a much more accurate estimate of the integral. To show that convergence is conditional, put absolute values, write the integral as an infinite series, and use the Mean Value Theorem in each subinterval:
$$
\int_1^{\infty} |x^2\cos(e^x)|\,dx>\int_{\log(3\pi/2)}^{\infty} x^2|\cos(e^x)|\,dx
$$
$$
= \sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{\log((2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2})}^{\log((2k+3)\frac{\pi}{2})} x^2|\cos(e^x)|\,dx
$$
$$
> \sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\log((2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2})\right)^2 \cdot \int_{\log((2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2})}^{\log((2k+3)\frac{\pi}{2})} |\cos(e^x)|\,dx
$$The integrand is concave, so we can underapproximate the integral by the triangle with vertices $\{(\log((2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}),0),(\log((k+1)\pi),1),(\log((2k+3)\frac{\pi}{2}),0)\}$:
$$
> \cdot \sum _{k=1}^{\infty} (\log((2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}))^2\cdot \frac{1}{2} \left(\log((2k+3)\frac{\pi}{2})-\log((2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2})\right)
$$Finally, this series diverges (one could use, for example, Ermakoff's Test, a variant of the Cauchy Condensation Test).